# Extract Date and Time in ABAP via Regex

Tags: regex, abap

I wanted to separate the time and date from this string using REGEX because I feel like it is the only way I can separate it. But I am not really familiar on how to do it maybe someone can help me out here.

The original string: **`Your item was delivered in or at the mailbox at 3:34 pm on September 1, 2016 in TEXAS, MT 59102`**

The output i want to achieve/populate:

- `lv_time = 3:34 pm`
- `lv_date = September 1, 2016`

Here's the code I was trying to do but I am only able to cut it like this:

- `lv_status = Your item was delivered in or at the mailbox at`
- `lv_time = 3`
- `lv_date = :34 pm on September 1, 2016 in TEXAS, MT 59102.`

Here's the code I have so far:

```
DATA: lv_status TYPE string,
      lv_time   TYPE string,
      lv_date  TYPE string,
      lv_off    TYPE i.

lv_status = 'Your item was delivered in or at the mailbox at 3:34 pm on September 1, 2016 in TEXAS, MT 59102.'.
FIND REGEX '(\d+)\s*(.*)' IN lv_status SUBMATCHES lv_time lv_date MATCH OFFSET lv_off.
lv_status = lv_status(lv_off).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked for it, here it comes:

```
\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm])) on (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\D?(\d{1,2}\D?)?\D?((?:19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})
```

This accepts time in `HH:MM am/pm` format, and dates in `Jan-Dec, dd 1970-2999`.
Each part is captured in its own group.

The demo shows a version that allows abbreviated month names:

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kYzlED/1)

Comment: Cool, Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you help me one last time for this string to get the date and time: "Out for Delivery, September 1, 2016, 8:47 am, TEXAS, MT 59102"

Comment: Not a problem, just use an alternation between date and time https://regex101.com/r/kYzlED/2